How to set/force EXE stack size with 1988 Turbo C 2.0 for a reverse engineering project
I am trying to reconstruct C source of a Turbo C 2.0 DOS small-memory-model executable as exactly as possible from disassembly (it’s a DOS reverse-engineering project and I’m using IDA Pro for disassembly, UASM for re-assembly and Turbo C 2.x for the C source reconstruction)
My first step was to find out the exact compiler for the reconstruction and the build settings that were used.  According to IDA Pro and the string "Turbo-C - Copyright (c) 1988 Borland Intl." within the executable, it seems to have been built with Turbo 2.0 or 2.01 from 1988 (not TC 1.5 because that would say 1987) – the only difference is that the example executable I produce with TC 2.0/2.01 contains an additional null pointer assignment string, but startup code seems to be more or less equal.
Now I am try to force the stack size of the resulting executable but can't get it to work – there is always a stack segment with the default size of 0x80 in the resulting executable.
According to http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part2/section-6.html, I could use _stklen in code or STACKSIZE from a DEF file to force a size, but _stklen seems to do nothing and I don't know the syntax for the DEF file or how to tell Turbo C to use the DEF file.
I've found some docs about _stklen but that sounds more like a read-only value and nothing about using DEF files with Turbo C.  Anyone with vague remembering how that worked exactly in the old times? :)
My test.c:
extern unsigned _stklen = 54321U;

int x = 10;

int main()
{
  int y;
  y = 10;
  return y;
}

Build step:
tcc -ms -M test.c

test.map:
 Start  Stop   Length Name               Class

 00000H 00559H 0055AH _TEXT              CODE
 00560H 00701H 001A2H _DATA              DATA
 00702H 00705H 00004H _EMUSEG            DATA
 00706H 00707H 00002H _CRTSEG            DATA
 00708H 00708H 00000H _CVTSEG            DATA
 00708H 00708H 00000H _SCNSEG            DATA
 00708H 0074DH 00046H _BSS               BSS
 0074EH 0074EH 00000H _BSSEND            STACK
 00750H 007CFH 00080H _STACK             STACK

Stack size is always 0x80.
more details about the Stack of the executable
(result from IDA Pro - reassembling create 100% binary equal executable)
; Segment type: Uninitialized
stack_seg   segment byte stack 'STACK'
        assume cs:stack_seg
        assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:dseg
        db 190h dup(?)
fixed_stack_var0 dw ?
fixed_stack_var1 dw ?
fixed_stack_var2 dw ?
fixed_stack_var3 dw ?
fixed_stack_var4 dw ?
fixed_stack_var5 dw ?
        db 2BCh dup(?)
stack_seg   ends

these Stack-Variables are used in the main and somewhere around - so it seems that the accesses really comming from the C original - and this is the "Stack-Layout" i try to replicate
found serveral functions like this one - that use self-modifying code (search for SELFMC) and direct access to stack segment (search ss:[) - i don't think its possible to do that in pure C (not even with inline asm)
sub_1D5D1 proc near   ; CODE XREF: sub_16769+2F7p

arg_0   = word ptr  4
arg_2   = word ptr  6
arg_4   = word ptr  8
arg_6   = word ptr  0Ah
arg_8   = word ptr  0Ch

; FUNCTION CHUNK AT D733 SIZE 0000000D BYTES

    push  bp
    mov bp, sp
    push  es
    push  ds
    push  di
    push  si
    mov ss:fixed_stack_var5, 0
    mov dx, 3C4h
    mov ax, 0F02h
    out dx, ax    ; EGA: sequencer address reg
          ; unknown register
    mov dl, 0CEh ; 'Î'
    mov ax, 3
    out dx, ax    ; EGA: graph 1 and 2 addr reg:
          ; data rotate and function select for write mode 00. Bits:
          ; 0-2: set rotate count for write mode 00
          ; 3-4: fn for write modes 00 and 02
          ;      00=no change; 01=AND; 10=OR; 11=XOR
    mov ax, 205h
    out dx, ax    ; EGA: graph 1 and 2 addr reg:
          ; unknown register
    mov al, 8
    out dx, al    ; EGA: graph 1 and 2 addr reg:
          ; bit mask
          ; Bits 0-7 select bits to be masked in all planes
    mov ax, [bp+arg_8]
    mov byte ptr cs:SELFMC_loc_1D683+1, al
    mov si, [bp+arg_2]
    mov ax, [bp+arg_6]
    cmp si, ax
    jle short loc_1D605
    xchg  ax, si

loc_1D605:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+31j
    mov dx, ss:fixed_stack_var1
    mov di, ss:fixed_stack_var2
    cmp si, dx
    jge short loc_1D61A
    mov si, dx
    jmp short loc_1D61E
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_1D617:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+4Bj
          ; sub_1D5D1+55j ...
    jmp loc_1D733
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_1D61A:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+40j
    cmp si, di
    jg  short loc_1D617

loc_1D61E:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+44j
    cmp ax, di
    jle short loc_1D624
    mov ax, di

loc_1D624:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+4Fj
    cmp ax, dx
    jl  short loc_1D617
    sub ax, si
    inc ax
    mov byte ptr cs:SELFMC_loc_1D69F+1, al
    mov byte ptr cs:SELFMC_loc_1D6C4+1, al
    mov byte ptr cs:SELFMC_loc_1D6E4+1, al
    mov dx, [bp+arg_0]
    mov bp, [bp+arg_4]
    cmp dx, bp
    jle short loc_1D643
    xchg  dx, bp

loc_1D643:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+6Ej
    mov ax, ss:fixed_stack_var3
    mov bx, ss:fixed_stack_var4
    cmp dx, ax
    jge short loc_1D652
    mov dx, ax

loc_1D652:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+7Dj
    cmp dx, bx
    jg  short loc_1D617
    cmp bp, bx
    jle short loc_1D65C
    mov bp, bx

loc_1D65C:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1+87j
    cmp bp, ax
    jl  short loc_1D617
sub_1D5D1 endp

; START OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_1D57F

loc_1D660::       ; CODE XREF: sub_1D57F:loc_1D5CEj
    shl si, 1
    mov si, ss:[si]
    mov ax, dx
    shr ax, 1
    shr ax, 1
    shr ax, 1
    add ax, si
    mov bx, ax
    mov ax, bp
    shr ax, 1
    shr ax, 1
    shr ax, 1
    add si, ax
    mov ds, VIDEO_PTR_1.segm
    mov ax, ds
    mov es, ax
; END OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_1D57F
    assume es:dseg

SELFMC_loc_1D683::      ; DATA XREF: sub_1D57F+25w
          ; sub_1D5D1+25w
    mov ah, 0
    cmp si, bx
    jz  short loc_1D707
    and dx, 7
    jz  short loc_1D6AB
    mov di, offset io_port_out_data2
    add di, dx
    mov al, cs:[di]
    mov dx, 3CFh
    out dx, al    ; EGA port: graphics controller data register
    mov dx, 28h ; '('
    mov di, bx

SELFMC_loc_1D69F::      ; DATA XREF: sub_1D57F+37w
          ; sub_1D5D1+5Aw
    mov cx, 0

loc_1D6A2:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D6A8j
    mov al, [di]
    mov [di], ah
    add di, dx
    loop  loc_1D6A2
    inc bx

loc_1D6AB:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D68Cj
    and bp, 7
    cmp bp, 7
    jz  short loc_1D6D0
    mov di, offset io_port_out_data1
    add di, bp
    mov al, cs:[di]
    mov dx, 3CFh
    out dx, al    ; EGA port: graphics controller data register
    mov dx, 28h ; '('
    mov di, si

SELFMC_loc_1D6C4::      ; DATA XREF: sub_1D57F+3Bw
          ; sub_1D5D1+5Ew
    mov cx, 0

loc_1D6C7:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D6CDj
    mov al, [di]
    mov [di], ah
    add di, dx
    loop  loc_1D6C7
    dec si

loc_1D6D0:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D6B1j
    sub si, bx
    jb  short loc_1D733
    mov dx, 3CFh
    mov al, 0FFh
    out dx, al    ; EGA port: graphics controller data register
    mov dx, si
    inc dx
    mov al, ah
    mov si, bx
    mov bx, 28h ; '('

SELFMC_loc_1D6E4::      ; DATA XREF: sub_1D57F+3Fw
          ; sub_1D5D1+62w ...
    mov bp, 0
    shr dx, 1
    jnb short loc_1D6FA
    mov di, si
    mov cx, bp

loc_1D6EF:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D6F3j
    mov [di], al
    add di, bx
    loop  loc_1D6EF
    inc si
    or  dx, dx
    jz  short loc_1D733

loc_1D6FA:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D6E9j seg000:D703j
    mov di, si
    mov cx, dx
    rep stosw
    add si, bx
    dec bp
    jnz short loc_1D6FA
    jmp short loc_1D733
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_1D707:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D687j
    and dx, 7
    mov di, dx
    add di, offset io_port_out_data2
    mov al, cs:[di]
    and bp, 7
    mov di, bp
    add di, offset io_port_out_data1
    and al, cs:[di]
    mov dx, 3CFh
    out dx, al    ; EGA port: graphics controller data register
    mov dx, 28h ; '('
    mov cx, word ptr cs:SELFMC_loc_1D6E4+1 ; loop-counter

loc_1D72B:        ; CODE XREF: seg000:D731j
    mov al, [si]
    mov [si], ah
    add si, dx
    loop  loc_1D72B
; START OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_1D5D1

loc_1D733:        ; CODE XREF: sub_1D5D1:loc_1D617j
          ; seg000:D6D2j ...
    mov ss:fixed_stack_var5, 1
    pop si
    pop di
    pop ds
    pop es
    assume es:nothing
    pop bp
    retn
; END OF FUNCTION CHUNK FOR sub_1D5D1

Compiler help:
Turbo C  Version 2.0  Copyright (c) 1987, 1988 Borland International
Syntax is: TCC [ options ] file[s]       * = default; -x- = turn switch x off
  -1      80186/286 Instructions          -A      Disable non-ANSI extensions
  -B      Compile via assembly            -C      Allow nested comments
  -Dxxx   Define macro                    -Exxx   Alternate assembler name
  -G      Generate for speed              -Ixxx   Include files directory
  -K      Default char is unsigned        -Lxxx   Libraries directory
  -M      Generate link map               -N      Check stack overflow
  -O      Optimize jumps                  -S      Produce assembly output
  -Uxxx   Undefine macro                  -Z      Optimize register usage
  -a      Generate word alignment         -c      Compile only
  -d      Merge duplicate strings         -exxx   Executable file name
  -f    * Floating point emulator         -f87    8087 floating point
  -gN     Stop after N warnings           -iN     Maximum identifier length N
  -jN     Stop after N errors             -k      Standard stack frame
  -lx     Pass option x to linker         -mc     Compact Model
  -mh     Huge Model                      -ml     Large Model
  -mm     Medium Model                    -ms   * Small Model
  -mt     Tiny Model                      -nxxx   Output file directory
  -oxxx   Object file name                -p      Pascal calls
  -r    * Register variables              -u    * Underscores on externs
  -v      Source level debugging          -w      Enable all warnings
  -wxxx   Enable warning xxx              -w-xxx  Disable warning xxx
  -y      Produce line number info        -zxxx   Set segment names

Linker help:
Turbo Link  Version 2.0  Copyright (c) 1987, 1988 Borland International
Syntax:  TLINK objfiles, exefile, mapfile, libfiles
@xxxx indicates use response file xxxx
Options: /m = map file with publics
         /x = no map file at all
         /i = initialize all segments
         /l = include source line numbers
         /s = detailed map of segments
         /n = no default libraries
         /d = warn if duplicate symbols in libraries
         /c = lower case significant in symbols
         /3 = enable 32-bit processing
         /v = include full symbolic debug information
         /e = ignore Extended Dictionary
         /t = create COM file

(I cross-posted this from Stack Overflow because someone told me that here is the better place to ask.)

What value does printing _stklen from the running program give? It's likely the size is adjusted in the C startup.

printf("_stklen: %u\n", _stklen); gives _stklen: 54321

The turbo c book sort of suggest that tiny memory model (-mt) doesn't have a stack segment.

@KelvinSherlock - its defintly a small-memory model with code, data and stack segment

I'm curious if you can impact the stack size with other memory models.  For example, if you compiled using -mm (medium I think); would changing _stklen have an impact?  That might provide a clue?  Good luck!

Are those lengths in bytes or paragraphs? Note 54321 probably isn't a valid value for either one (odd number of bytes, too large if paragraphs) so maybe it is being ignored. What about a more reasonable value like 0x400?

@Nate Eldredge - i tried 0x400 - still 0x80 size

if you want a custom stack size, turbo asm seems to have a .STACK directive, so maybe it was done with that.  with inline asm, maybe it would be asm .STACK 1112

@Kelvin Sherlock - i currently think its a mixture of plain C with many assembler based routines (maybe some inline asm) but more likely an external assembler

Run link.exe /? and see if it has a /STACK option?

@John Dallman - added compiler/linker help - can't see a stack option

@llm: Agree, it isn't there. Take the extern qualifier off _stklen and see if that makes a difference? At present, there is no storage assigned for it, and it might need to exist to work.

As a comment unrelated to my answer: nearly everything is possible using "inline asm" in Turbo C 1.5 / Turbo C 2.0, even self modifying code and SS prefixes. The Turbo C IDE does not implement inline assembly at all, and the command-line compiler only supports it in the compile-via-assembler mode, in which tcc writes an asm file which is passed to tasm. The contents of inline assembly are mostly pasted literally into the assembly file, so "anything goes". It does not really make sense to use inline ASM that way though, a dedicated ASM file is better managable.

For what (little) it's woth: .def files are only used for Windows programs, not MS-DOS programs.

Your observation is correct that the assembly code you quoted is clearly not generated by the Turbo C compiler, but it is hand-written assembly code. The Turbo C compiler will not generate self-modifying code, and it will not generate SS segment overrides for data access. This does not necessarily mean that the SS overrides are hand-written, though. This is a point we will discuss later.
As the "small" memory model does not include a segment value in standard "data pointers", and you likely want to be able to pass both pointers to local stack variables as pointers to global data variables around as "data pointers", the value of SS and DS is assumed to be the same. The SS override on data access thus only makes sense if one assumes that DS might point to a different segment, for example a segment containing source data for graphics that should be painted in a 16-color EGA graphics mode. The Turbo C compiler will not generate code that changes DS, and it will access the stack, the heap and global data variables without any segment overrides.
As just discussed, accessing global data via DS is the same as accessing global data via SS. The things you called fixed_stack_var are just global data variables, that for "some reason" are accessed using SS instead of DS. Assuming DS and SS are identical at that point (which they likely are), the SS segment prefix is useless, takes up extra code space and depending on the processor also some extra execution time. This prefix is most likely not intentionally there.
The Microsoft Assembler (and by compatibility also the Turbo Assembler) automatically insert segment overrides to access variables that are not accessible via the standard segment registers. The Assembler uses the ASSUME directive for that. I guess the author of the hand-written assembly code used an ASSUME ds:nothing statement, because at some places in that code, DS does not point to the standard "small model" data segment. This causes the Assembler to auto-pick a different segment register that is known to point to the "small model" data segment. As already discussed, the stack is located in that 64K segment, so the assembler resorts to using SS because it is told to assume that DS is unusable.
In the end, this means that what you called "fixed_stack_var" are actually standard data segment variables. The stack only starts after them. There is no technical way for IDA to tell apart what is in the "stack" segment and what is in the data segment, because DS == SS. IDA gueses what is intended to be "stack" by the segment register used, but given the circumstances in this code, IDA guessed wrong. As you see, the "fixed_stack_var" variables are uninitialized. They should be part of the second half of the data segment, called "bss", which is cleared to zero by the start-up code. If I remember correctly, IDA doesn't create dedicated segments for "data" (initialized from EXE file contents) and "bss" (uninitialized by DOS, cleared by the Turbo C startup code), so the "fixed_stack_var" stuff actually belongs to the end of bss instead of the start of stack.
There is no "stack size" declared in the EXE file. The EXE header contains the initial value for SS (which is just the standard "small model" data segment) and SP, so there is a pointer to the end of the stack, but there is no indication where the logical area called "stack" starts. The stack size displayed by the linker is a fixed value in C0S.OBJ which you are unable to change, unless you acutally modify C0S.OBJ. You don't have to, though. The initial stack is used only at the very start of the startup code, DOS is told to dynamically modify the size of memory reserved for the program, so that a new "heap" area can be created, followed by the user-level "stack" area. The variables _stklen and _heaplen influence the size of the heap and the user-level stack generated by the startup code, not the stack declared in the EXE file.
So what can you do to reproduce the EXE file? I told you that you don't need to adjust the stack size, and that's because the linker just puts the uninitialized stack just behind the uninitialized data (BSS) segment. As you know, the initial stack is 128 bytes, so the initial stacks starts 0x2BC - 0x80 = 0x23C bytes after fixed_stack_var5, which I already explained to be part of the bss segment. So just place a db 23Ch dup (?) after fixed_stack_var5 into the assembly source file for that code, and check whether it matches up.

"The Turbo C compiler will not generate self-modifying code [...]" That's....sort of true, but sort of not. Although it's probably not actually generated by the compiler, Borland's startup routine contained some self-modifying code, so it's entirely normal for Turbo C programs to contain some self-modifying code.

@Michael Karcher - thanks for the detailed explanation - it will check if SS=DS in that case (with the debugger), always thought that the SS part in the exe-header (with offset=0) is the stack start

"correct myself": it is the stack start but IDA miss-detecting the vars inside the stack segment

so i checked the registers with dosbox debugger: at start DS=0x0F66 and SS=0x1840 - at the first access to ss:fixed_stack_var1 SS and DS are still like at start and not the same, and i really don't see a good reason why the linker should not set the SS-segment in the exe to the correct start of the stack

in the exe-header...

@llm It seems you are not in the small model in that case. This will also explain the reason why you don't have the "null pointer" message. That message is only present in the start-up code for "near data" models, i.e. tiny, small and medium, but not in the "far data" models compact and large/huge.
You should double-check that your code is not actually "compact" (near code, far data).
Check the number of pushes when calling main in the startup. 3 pushes = near data, 5 pushes = far data.

5 pushes = so compact model? why is the data-far at all - very strange? here the 3 functions from start->main->first acces to a fixed_stack_var (https://pastebin.com/x9ntFpZa - line 128(call main)->150->151->216->291(access fixed_var))

This will also explain the reason why you don't have the "null pointer" message. - thank you - i never thought of a relation to the memory model

@Michael Karcher - thank you again, never thought that i will someone with that deep tiny-detail knowlege about Turbo C - where did you learned this "null pointer message" is only contained in compact/huge model? btw: im also from germany

@llm Using "far data" means that every data pointer passed around contains a segment and an offset. This enables you to pass around data pointers to everywhere in the 1MB PC address space, not just to your local program data segment. This is very convenient if you want to be able to use all kind of library functions on special address regions like the BIOS or video memory. All standard global data managed by Turbo C is still contained in the same 64K, and DS will always point to it in C-compiled functions. This is an optimization so you don't have to reload DS...

... when accessing any kind of global variable. This is the difference between "large" and "huge". In "huge", every .C file gets its own data segment and every function re-loads DS when it gets called. As library functions can deal with data in any segment, though, there is no need to put the stack in the same segment as the global data. These functions have to pay the price to load the segment contained in that pointer anyway. So to leave more space for global variables, the stack in compact/large/huge is generated outside of the 64K global data segment.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
